# variable in supervisor config file

Tags: templates, supervisord

I want to avoid "code duplication" in my supervisor config file.

In short supervisor has to launch a script with two parameters that are very similar:

```
command=my_script --param1=/path/to/bar.txt --param2=/path/to/foo.txt
```

I want to avoid the duplication of `path/to`.

I tried

```
[program:my_program]
PATHTO="/path/to"
command=my_script --param1=%(ENV_PATHTO)sbar.txt --param2=%(ENV_PATHTO)sfoo.txt
```

I've tried some variations with `environment=PATHTO="/path/to"`, `${PATHTO}`, etc.

Nothing seems to work.

Questions :

1. how to define variables in a supervisor config file ?
2. Is there a concept of "template" config file ?

Answer (score 1):

According to file format section in document:

http://supervisord.org/configuration.html?#file-format

[image]

environment variables that are present in the environment at the time that supervisord is started can be used in the configuration file using the Python string expression syntax %(ENV_X)s.

and variables in `environment=PATHTO="/path/to"` will be inherited by child processes. This does not change the environment of supervisord itself.

http://supervisord.org/configuration.html?#supervisord-section-values

[image: supervisord section value - environment]